# C++ Error no match for operator << when trying to display a list

Tags: c++, cout

I don't know what's wrong with this code, I'm a c++ newbie, could someone help me fix it? I've been having issues with this for some time and I don't know how to fix it. I've tried messing with the code, but to no success. Anyone know what's wrong with this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

void rising(double T[], int n)
{
    double pom;
    for (int j=n-1;j>0;j--)
    for (int i=0;i<j;i++)
    if (T[i]>T[i+1])
    {
        pom=T[i];
        T[i]=T[i+1];
        T[i+1]=pom;
    }
}
void lowering(double T[], int n)
{
    double pom;
    for (int j=n-1;j>0;j--)
    for (int i=0;i<j;i++)
    if (T[i]<T[i+1])
    {
        pom=T[i];
        T[i]=T[i+1];
        T[i+1]=pom;
    }
}
void show(double T[], int n)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    cout<<T[i]<<setw(3);
    cout<<endl;
}
int main()
{
    double tablica[]={2, 12, 3, 4, 5, 4, 7, 8, 9, 9, 0};
    cout<<"elementy tablicy to: "<<show(tablica,11)<<endl;
    cout<<"elementy tablicy posortowane rosnaco: "<<rising(tablica,11)<<endl;
    cout<<"elementy tablicy posortowane malejaco: "<<lowering(tablica,11)<<endl;
    cin.get();
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your functions don't return anything, so there is nothing that you can pass to `cout`

Comment: how do they not return anything? is there a way to fix that?

Comment: They are declared with a return type of `void`, and they don't contain a `return someValue;` statement. That's how.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a c++ newbie, could you fix the code for me, if you can of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your functions have void return type, there is nothing `<<` operator can do with them, fortunately you already have the functions to do what you want, you just have to call them in the correct fashion and order:

```
int main()
{
    double tablica[]={2, 12, 3, 4, 5, 4, 7, 8, 9, 9, 0};
    cout<<"elementy tablicy to: ";
    show(tablica,11);
    rising(tablica,11);
    cout<<"elementy tablicy posortowane rosnaco: ";
    show(tablica,11);
    lowering(tablica,11);
    cout<<"elementy tablicy posortowane malejaco: ";
    show(tablica,11);
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Oh my god I'm so dumb, it works now, appeciate it

Comment: @Daveman426, it happens, glad I could help, don't forget to [accept one of the answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
 cout<<"elementy tablicy to: "<<show(tablica,11)<<endl;

<<show(tablica,11)
```

to function show does not return any value (its return type is void),

you can simply call the function to perform its print:

```
int main()
{
    double tablica[] = { 2, 12, 3, 4, 5, 4, 7, 8, 9, 9, 0 };
    cout << "elementy tablicy to: ";
    show(tablica, 11);
```

Comment: For the rest you will have to call show() after the other function.